# What's the underlying technology behind MySQL Workbench GUI?

Tags: user-interface, mysql-workbench

I would like to know which technology is used to display MySQL Workbench GUI.
My suspect is that is using Java FX but I'm not pretty sure about this.

Comment: -1 This question was not well researched at all. OP can easily download the source to [MySQL Workbench here](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/tools/workbench/)

Comment: Yes. You're right. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: He can also "easily" download the source to Java, but that doesn't mean he can understand it. There is nothing wrong with the question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

MySQL Workbench is an application written mostly in C++. There are platform specific parts written in C# (Windows) and Objective-C (Mac). Frameworks used for the GUI are:

- .NET on Windows
- GTK on Linux
- Cocoa on Mac

Plugins can be created using either C++, Python or Lua. A big part of the administrator section in MySQL Workbench has been written in Python. The platform specific parts are wrapped by a thin layer called `mforms` that is used by the application and can be accessed by plugins (including those written in Python or Lua). The first version was created on Windows using Microsoft Visual Studio 2005 and later enhanced for Mac OS X and Linux.

**Update:**

Beginning with version 6.1 Lua support has been removed.

**Update 2:**

Since October 2015 the community code is [available from Github](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-workbench).